# Python + Selenium: Finish recaptcha after response has been submitted?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So far my code works as expected, it gets a "g-recaptcha-response" from a captcha service (https://anti-captcha.com), and inserts it to the recaptcha that is on the site. Now my problem comes here: what to do after it has been submitted? even tho the recaptcha response gets submitted, the recaptcha doesnt reach the checkmark point where it is completed. What is the last step i need to do to complete the recaptcha here? thank you in advance :]
Python Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from anticaptchaofficial.recaptchav2proxyless import *

DRIVER = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
DRIVER.get("https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/")

data_sitekey = WebDriverWait(DRIVER, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "g-recaptcha"))).get_attribute("data-sitekey")
print(data_sitekey)

solver = recaptchaV2Proxyless()
solver.set_verbose(1)
solver.set_key("135986148491286418614")
solver.set_website_url("https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/")
solver.set_website_key(data_sitekey)

g_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution()
if g_response != 0:
    print("g-response: "+g_response)
else:
    print("task finished with error "+solver.error_code)

DRIVER.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML='" + g_response + "';");

#execute_script(submit button)??? or what do i need to do here to finish the captcha
```